# update an activity when click on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using push notifications in Android. When I receive a push notification and click on it it launchs an activity as i want , but if this activity it's already opened nothing happened , the activity keeps the old data.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Detail"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ma.via.marocagenda.Home" />
    </activity>
```

GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
...
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    //int icon = R.drawable.abc_ic_go;
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Detail.class);
    // put extra for details
    notificationIntent.putExtra("id", VAL_TAG_ID);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("titre", VAL_TAG_TITRE);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    notificationIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    //PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

what can be wrong ?

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: if the "detail" activity is already launched , and click on the notification nothing happened , the activity is not updated with new data

Comment: Override onNewIntent too?

Comment: @Deucalion can u explain more about overriding onNewIntent ?

Comment: Something like in in my old [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233202/decide-what-touching-notification-icon-does/17233946#17233946)

Comment: now i get the opposit problem , if i open the detail activity and click on notification it's getting updated as i want , but if i'm on other activities and i click on notification i get always the last detail activity data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can override `onNewIntent()` in your Activity to get the Latest Intent From the Notification.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (intent.hasExtra("key")){
            //do your Stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Local broadcasts from your service whenever a push notification arrives.

> For how to use Local broadcasts read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/826657

Let your activity register for this broadcast action, and when a push notification is received, update the activity from `onReceive()`.

Also, being more specific using ActivityManager you can check that if you activity is on top, if true send the broadcast also, else just show the notification.

> Read here for how to find the current foreground activity.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753333/826657

Comment: as you can see in my code, in the generateNotification method i want launch the **detail** activity only when click on notification  not when i receive it